# How to customize the Alfred app to show full dictionary definitions without opening the dictionary app

Tags: macos, dictionary, alfred

I'm using the [Alfred app](http://www.alfredapp.com/) for Mac OS X.  One thing I can do with the app is search for words to define with OS X's dictionary.  In the app it shows a short preview of the definition but to show the full definition I need to open the dictionary app.  Is there a way to customize Alfred to show the full definition right when I search?

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't anyway to do that. Alfred is designed to display one result per row, so all you can see of each definition is what fits on the subtitle of the corresponding result row.